# How to update image with its sub-pixels in java?

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm using Image to show a picture in java,now I have a `image` object which type is `BufferedImage` with mxn pixels, now I want to modify (m-1)x(n-1) pixels and let the image have (m-1)x(n-1) pixels only,meaning to resize its size to (m-1)x(n-1).How can I do it?Anyone knows can teach me,thanks very much!

Comment: try to google your question

Comment: @Blip,I have searched this question in google,but I can't get my answer.If you know,please teach me how to make it.

Comment: Draw the image object on a graphics2D and then use the graphics2D to generate a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what i want to do is resize the image with its pre (m-1)x(n-1) pixels, meaning drop last row and last column

Seems to me like you want to create a new image from your BufferedImage.

Check out the `getSubimage(...)` method of the `BufferedImage` API.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  `getRGB(x,y)` and `setRGB(x,y,rgb)` to get and set the specified pixels of an [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Comment: thx,but i know how to change pixel, but what i want to do is resize the image with its pre (m-1)x(n-1) pixels, meaning drop last row and last column and repaint it.

Comment: Oh ok, then I didn't get you question right. Do you want to only drop these pixels or do you also want to change the other pixels to get the same image but scaled?